# How do I parse r help files - what arguments are actually optional?

Tags: r

The help file for lm is here: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/lm.html or you can do ?lm. Some parameters are specified as optional while others are not. Yet I find:

```
r=x~y
x=1:10
y=1:10*2
lm(r)
```

works fine. How can I interpret what's required and what's actually optional?

Comment: As @bondeddust points out, it's best to look at the help file and add anything that doesn't have a default value (e.g., formula or data). In practice, I find it's usually better to explicitly set most of the arguments as the default behavior can change over time, especially with developing packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of looking at the Usage and Arguments sections usually suffices:

## Usage:

```
lm(formula, data, subset, weights, na.action,
   method = "qr", model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE,
   singular.ok = TRUE, contrasts = NULL, offset, ...)
```

Every named argument before the triple dots except arguably `offset` is either mentioned in the Details as having a default or is listed in the Usage as being assigned a default value. Any value beyond the triple dots in an argument list is automatically not required. You can also look at the code. In the case of `offset` it is clear from this line that a NULL value is acceptable:

```
if (!is.null(offset)) {
```

Comment: Sounds good. I'm used to matlab where these things are muss less negotiable.